# Vue: Show image from Storage as Background

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Actually I have this code, where I access to assets folder(inside of public).

```
<div class="itemProjectImage"  :id="'itemProjectImage_'+i" :style="'background-image:url(/assets/img/projects/'+project.slug+'/home.jpg'">
</div>
```

What I really want is access like this to storage, but with vue.

```
<p class="lead"><img src="{{ asset('/storage/employees/'.$employee->slug.'/'.$employee->slug.'.'.'jpg') }}" width="50%" ></p>
```

¿Which is the correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I this scenerios you have to store the complete absolute path in your database which points to public folder.

you can store your images using `asset('your path')` while storing.

Comment: Hi @AdnanMumtaz as you can see, I can access to storage, the line: `<p class="lead"><img src="{{ asset('/storage/employees/'.$employee->slug.'/'.$employee->slug.'.'.'jpg') }}" width="50%" ></p>` but don't know how to do it with vue

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer while storing you should use absolute path to database.

Comment: But I don't want to put absolute path to database, i want to access to storage folder:l

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer Dear you can use `asset(storage/your path)` to your database. then you can access it in Vue. else you can have global variable which has a base path of your app.

Comment: Mmm.. so, with this must works? ` <div class="itemProjectImage"  :id="'itemProjectImage_'+i" :style="'background-image:url(asset('/app/projects/'+project.slug+'/home.jpg'')">` this have a syntax error, know where?